# SQL Join For Exact Result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have the following table in my database. Its purpose is to hold colour sets. I.e. [red + black], [blue + green + yellow], etc.

```
CREATE TABLE `df_productcolours` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_colourSet` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_colour` int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`id_colourSet`,`id_colour`),
  KEY `idx_colourSet` (`id_colourSet`),
  KEY `idx_colour_id` (`id_colour`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_colourid` FOREIGN KEY (`id_colour`) REFERENCES `df_lu_color` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I made a stored proc that takes an array of id_colour integers as input, and returns a colour set id. What it's meant to do is return the set that contains those colours, and ONLY those colours that are provided as input. What it's actually doing is returning sets that contain the colours requested plus some others.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempTable_inputColours);

SELECT A.id_colourSet
FROM df_productcolours AS A
INNER JOIN tempTable_inputColours AS B
    ON A.id_colour = B.id_colour
GROUP BY A.id_colourSet
HAVING COUNT(A.id_colour) = @count
    AND COUNT(B.id_colour) = @count;
```

I have a feeling the issue may be with the way I'm joining, but I just can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: id serves no purpose here. I suggest you delete it and set your unique key as primary.

Comment: thanks, any thoughts on the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it myself after a few days of punishment. Here's the code:

```
SET clrCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _tmp_ColourSet);

-- The first half of the query does an inner join, 
-- it will return all sets that have ANY of our requested colours. 
-- But the HAVING condition will make it return sets that have AT LEAST all of the colours we are requesting.
-- So at this point we have all the super-sets, if you will.
-- Then, the second half of the query will restrict that further, 
-- to only sets that have the same number of colours as we are requesting.
-- And voila :)

                      -- FIND ALL COLOUR SETS THAT HAVE ALL REQUESTED COLOURS
    SET colourSetId = (SELECT A.id_colourSet 
                        FROM df_productcolours AS A
                        INNER JOIN _tmp_colourset AS B
                            ON A.id_colour = B.id_colour
                        GROUP BY A.id_colourSet
                        HAVING COUNT(A.id_colour) = clrCount
                        -- FIND ALL COLOUR SETS THAT HAVE EXACTLY N COLOURS
                        AND A.id_colourSet IN (SELECT A.id_colourSet
                                                FROM df_productcolours AS A
                                                GROUP BY A.id_colourSet
                                                HAVING COUNT(A.id_colour) = clrCount));
```

Hope it saves someone pulling their hair out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.id_colourSet
FROM df_productcolours AS A
INNER JOIN tempTable_inputColours AS B
ON A.id_colour = B.id_colour
WHERE A.id_colourSet IN (SELECT id_colour FROM tempTable_inputColours)
AND A.id_colour IN (SELECT id_colour FROM tempTable_inputColours)
```

#### EDIT

```
SELECT A.id_colourSet
FROM df_productcolours AS A
INNER JOIN tempTable_inputColours AS B
ON A.id_colour = B.id_colour
WHERE A.id_colourSet =(SELECT SUM(id_colour) FROM tempTable_inputColours)
```

Comment: This will fail: it will only check that result has *at least one* of colors, not *all of them*

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer: color and its set have to be in the input table

Comment: On the second-last line you are comparing colour set to colour id

Comment: if you have (color_id1,color_id2,color_id3) as an input. Are you looking for all possible sum combinations between the 3 inputs?: color_id1+color_id2 OR color_id1+color_id3 OR color_id2+color_id3 OR ... or exactly the sum of the 3 colors. Just to make sure if I uderstood the question

Comment: Thanks, I need exactly (and only) the sum of the 3 colours

Comment: I tried to update my answer not sure if I good understood the question

Comment: can you provide some inputs to your 2 tables in an sqlfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82909/discussion-between-mils-and-amani).